# readline() method in python

Tags: python, readline

I found the following on internet but I am not able to understand it. Can anybody please explain me this in an easy manner. I tried ChatGPT but it didn't help.

I know what readline() method in python does but I found this website https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-the-differences-between-readline-and-readlines-in-selenium-with-python

I am not able to understand the second point under readline() which says:

`A new line character is left at the string end and is ignored for the last line provided the file does not finish in a new line.`

I tried chat ChatGPT, it says this:

`This can be important because sometimes you want to know if a line had a "new line character" or not, especially when you're working with the contents of the file in your program. It helps you figure out where one line ends and the next begins, even if the file itself doesn't make it very clear.`

I didn't understand this either. I would be a big help if someone can explain me both of these

Comment: The `readline` function reads a whole line, including the newline, and puts it into the string it returns. That's about it. If the last line doesn't end with a newline, none is added to the string it returns. To simplify it even further, perhaps it can be said that the `readline` function copy-pastes the full line, as is, and without modifications, into the string it returns.

Comment: don't use tutorialspoint.com, just read the official docs

Answer (score 0):

The new line character is a line break. Within strings it is always displayed as a `"\n"`.

So your textfile that you have read in normally looks like the following:

```
"Some text.\n"
"More text.\n"
"End"
```

Which would be displayed like:

Some text.

More text.

End.

The description simply says that there will always be a line break at the end of a line you have read except the last one as there isn't a next line to read.

Greetings Fischi.

Comment: "The description simply says that there will always be a line break at the end of a line you have read except the last one as there isn't a next line to read." well, that is not normally the case, it should be pointed out. Basically what it's saying in this very confusing phrasing is that a newline is left on the last line depending on whether or not the file ends in a newline. It's confusing because it says "ignored" but it actually means the *opposite* of ignored

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Does that means the sentence is grammatically incorrect? The new line character is considered instead of ignored?